# Can I use react-native app's AppDelegate in ios module?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am writing iOS SDK wrapper for react native.
And the SDK guide gave me the code :

```
-(void)didClickOpenOfferwallBtn 
{
    [AdPopcornOfferwall openOfferWallWithViewController:self delegate:self userDataDictionaryForFilter:nil];
    [AdPopcornOfferwall shared].delegate = self;
}
```

So I think if I can get my react-native App's AppDelegate, (like Androids's getReactApplicationContext or getCurrentActivity functions) I can run the code inside of react-native ios module.

Are there some methods to get my current app's AppDelegate in React Native module?